# how to extract rows from excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have [an excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S36yTdDyvfYyRuAbzi2v1YMmhSf030Gk_vdz1u6ohKM/edit?usp=sharing). How can I extract data so that in python it looks like:

```
list = [['Igor', '20', 'SSU]'], ['Sergay', '19', 'SSTU'], ['Nadya', '21', 'SSAU']]
```

using **import xlrd**

Comment: what have you tried so far...?

Comment: something like [that](https://gist.github.com/gagareg/0af52b849944eabb71865ba8d2155f27)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a list using the following:

```
# Import:
import xlrd 

# Setting Path of File and Initializing List:
location = ("path of file") 
list = []

# Opening the Workbook and Defining Which Sheet to Use:
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(location) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

# Starting at Row 0 and Column 0:
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

# Iterating Over the Number of Rows and Appending to List:
for i in range(1, sheet.nrows + 1):
   list.append(sheet.row_values(i))
```

You could also loop through each of the sheets in the workbook by wrapping the `wb.sheet_by_index` in a for loop with the number of sheets. You may also want to run some checks to make sure the row isn't empty.

Please excuse any errors, my Python dealing with Excel is slightly rusty.

Comment: it does not work it shows errors 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isamarskii/Downloads/task_2/stack.py", line 17, in <module>
    list.append(sheet.row_values(i))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 492, in row_values
    return self._cell_values[rowx][start_colx:]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That may be because the range. Update the range to start with 1 and try adding a print statement in the for loop to make sure things are getting added to the list. For example `print(sheet.row_values(i))`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just changed `for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):` and now it works well. Thank you :)